# Vim Mode Plus Mark Occurrence for search

Tags: vim, atom-editor

When I type `/foo` and then enter, is there a way to mark occurrence for all highlighted words?  Right now, the `/`search seems pretty useless compared to the regular atom search, since it only highlights but doesn't let you replace.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I can't mark occurrence if I press `enter`.  However, I can do some things if I haven't pressed `enter`.

- `cmd-o` marks all search occurrences
- `ctr-cmd-c` waits for you to specify a range, and then changes all search occurrences

Answer (score 2):

The key `/` is used for searching, whereas `:s` for **s**ubstitutions (i.e. replacements). So to replace `foo` with `bar` you can do:

```
:%s/foo/bar/gc
```

Here `%` means look for replacements in the entire file, and the last `gc` are replacement flags. The Vim documentation provides a great explanation of the topic and it can be accessed by typing `:help subs`. To learn more about replacement flags: `:h flags`.

Comment: I'm using atom's vim mode plus, and I don't think I can use `:s`

Comment: I see, then I would suggest to take a look at [this discussion on github](https://github.com/t9md/atom-vim-mode-plus/issues/463) which may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Some more suggestions for a good workflow (at least in Vim itself):

- After using `/foo` to locate a match, and you only want to replace that one: As the cursor is at the start of the match, you can use `ce`, `cE` or more generally `cgn` (`gn` selects the current / next match; it's a recent addition in version 8.0).
- If you want to replace all matches, you don't need to repeat the search pattern in the `:substitute` command; an empty `{pattern}` there will recall the search pattern. So, you can briefly write `:%s//bar/g` (+ `c` to interactively influence replacements).